# Expected value of $X$ given $X > 15$

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a poisson random variable with $\lambda =\frac{1}{15}$, what is the expected value of $X$ given $X > 15$ ? I should know this but it's been a while since my intro to probability class.

Comment: Is this relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709504/memoryless-property-for-poisson-distribution ?

Comment: The definition of the conditional expectation: $$E[X|A]=\frac{E[X \ I_A]}{P(A)}$$ $I$ is the indicator function. Can you figure out what $A$ is in your specific case is?

Comment: Intuitively, because the distribution is falling *rapidly* when we are this much greater than the mean, the expectation will be $16+\epsilon$.  You will almost never have $X \ge 17$