# Poisson and memorylessness

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

You arrive at the bus stop at 10 o’clock, knowing that bus arrivals follow a Poisson distribution
with a rate of two buses per hour.

i.  What is the probability that you will have to wait longer than 10 minutes?

ii.  If, at 10:15, the bus has not yet arrived, what is the probability that you will have to wait at
least an additional 10 minutes?

If you solve this problem, you get the exact same answer (around 0.717) for both i, and ii. However, I have seen elsewhere that Poisson is not memoryless. Is that consistent with this problem? It seems to me that Poisson is memoryless based on this problem.

Comment: See the accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709504/memoryless-property-for-poisson-process

Comment: @saulspatz thank you for your answer. So just to clarify, i and ii should not then give the same answer right?

Comment: Yes, they certainly should.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m confused. If they should, then by definition isn’t Poisson memoryless? This is not very clear in the answer in the post you linked to

Comment: It's the distribution inter-arrival times that is memoryless.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks I believe I understand now. Since you brought up the other post though, do you mind explaining why P(N(20)=6∣N(10)=0)=P(N(20)−N(10)=6) is true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100376/discussion-between-user10796158-and-saulspatz).